# Create line in JSON foreach ARRAY values

Tags: javascript, json

Hey guys i'm trying to use handlebars templating and for that i need to create a json from array values

```
{"path":"Avions", "fileName":"AvionsEdit.vue"},{"path":"Avions", 
"fileName":"AvionsShow.vue"}ect...
```

i can return a json like in the code's part but i want something like

```
{"path":["Avions","Avions"],"fileName": 
["AvionsEdit.vue","AvionsShow.vue"]}

var foo = {"path" : [], "fileName": []};
for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   foo.path.push(list[i]);
   foo.fileName.push(list[i]+extList[i]+".vue");
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

here is my list

```
['Avions',
'Avions']
```

and here is my extList

```
['Edit',
'Show']
```

Comment: Can you provide list and extList variables

Comment: If `list` and `extList` have same number of items, this should work fine. What's the issue you're facing? Please provide the input and expected output.

Comment: list and extList have same length

Comment: now I'm a bit confused, your extList contains some data that was not present in the initial version of your question, it is more or less clear what you're trying to achieve, but I'm lost at what is your source data, could you share some bigger sample to understand the logic?

Comment: oh yeah my bad my file is a way to long so i've just cut him into a little piece but i failed i edit that now

Comment: Can you show us an example output?

Comment: {"path":["Avions","Avions"],"fileName": 
["AvionsEdit.vue","AvionsShow.vue"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel myself somewhat oldfashioned, using all those nested for loops, but I couldn't make up anything else (highly dependent upon source data consistency, though pretty straightforward and readable):

```js
var srcData = {
  "path": [
    "somepath",
    "anotherpath",
    "yetanotherpath"
  ],
  "filename": [
    "somefilename",
    "anotherfile",
    "yetanotherfile"
  ]
};

const transform = src => {
   let res = [];
   let attributes = Object.keys(src);
   for(let i = 0; i < Object.values(src)[0].length; i++){
      let entry = {};
      for(let j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++){
          entry[attributes[j]] = Object.values(src)[j][i];
      }
      res.push(entry);
   }
   return res;
};

console.log(transform(srcData));
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your new comments, i was waiting some notifications but it never comes.
I have created a function that generates the desired output.
These different arguments are:

- Path : List of your path or prefix
- File : FileName
- suffix : suffix/extension of your file

```js
var path = [ // path or prefix
      "path",
      "otherPath",
      "finalPath"
    ];
    var files = [ // file

      "Edit",
      "Get",
      "Foo"

    ];
console.log(transform(path,files,".vue")); 


 function transform(path, files,suffix) { // take your path, file and the suffix of your file
      if (path.length == files.length) { // check if the length is the same
        let results = { "path": [], "filename": [] }; // generate an object for the return
        for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
          results.path.push(path[i]); // push in the path array 
          results.filename.push(path[i]+files[i]+suffix) // push in the file name array. Concatenate the Path + File + the suffix

        }
        return results;
      }
    }
```

Comment: ygorbunkov has the great answer sorry for my bad english

Comment: Ok, np so I misunderstand your output expectation. According to your last comment your output was like mine and not him.

Comment: yeah that was my actual output but not the expected one